# Why if clicking print button first time its getting null values second time its getting exact value

Tags: jquery, ajax

Why if clicking print button first time its getting null values  second time its getting exact value  using jquery

Below my code is funtion is their please help from this.

```js
function PrevSchdcreateID() {
    $("#tblPrevSchdcreateJobCardMaster a").click(function () {
        alert("print");
        job_card_no = this.id;

        if ($(this).text() == "Print") {
            $("#divMain").hide();
            $("#dvPrevSchdPrintDetails").show();
            getMthStmt_ChkList_WorkPermit_Resources(this.id);
            Print("dvPrevSchdPrintDetails", "Preventive Maintenance");
            $("#divMain").show();
            $("#dvPrevSchdPrintDetails").hide();
        } else {
            $("#dvPrevSchdPrintDetails").css("dispaly", "none");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: no need to enclose it with a function..

Comment: add a jsfiddle to your question, to understand it clearly..

Comment: Where are you getting null values? Also, you have a typo: `dispaly` should be `display` (but why not just use `.hide()` instead of setting CSS?)

Comment: In this div dvPrevSchdPrintDetails iam getting null values

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#tblPrevSchdcreateJobCardMaster a").click(function () {
    alert("print");
    job_card_no = this.id;

    if ($(this).text() == "Print") {
        $("#divMain").hide();
        $("#dvPrevSchdPrintDetails").show();
        getMthStmt_ChkList_WorkPermit_Resources(this.id);
        Print("dvPrevSchdPrintDetails", "Preventive Maintenance");
        $("#divMain").show();
        $("#dvPrevSchdPrintDetails").hide();
    }
    else {
        $("#dvPrevSchdPrintDetails").css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

just use it like this.. without enclosing to any function.

Comment: Thank u,P but print button is not responding if without enclosing to any function. so what should i do.